# Validate value prop before method on @input event runs? VeeValidate/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

**Code Sandbox with exact example**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-components-vuetify-iftco

In the example above, when I enter a wrong value in the input field, the Validation state returns `Valid == true`, but it should return `false`.

I understand that this happens because the `@input` event method (`resize`) will run first and then it will assign the value to `:value`. In other words, `vee-validate` checks the existing value before the event is fired.

Not sure how to fix it so that the input value is first validated and then the method is run!

**How to replicate problem:**

1. Open the console
2. Change the value of the `width` field to 5
3. You will successfully get an error message under the field but the Valid flag in the console is set to true, even though the field is not valid after the method is done.

I am not sure how to fix this. I have been trying for hours..

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-row>
      <v-col v-for="(value, key) in fixture.dimensions" :key="key">
        <ValidationProvider
          :rules="`between:${fixture.limits[key].min},${fixture.limits[key].max}`"
          v-slot="{ errors, valid }"
        >
          <v-text-field
            :value="fixture.dimensions[key]"
            @input="resize(key, valid)"
            :label="key"
            ref="key"
            :min="fixture.limits[key].min"
            :max="fixture.limits[key].max"
            :error-messages="errors"
            outlined
            type="number"
          ></v-text-field>
        </ValidationProvider>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ValidationProvider
  },
  data: () => ({
    fixture: {
      dimensions: {
        width: 1000,
        height: 1500
      },
      limits: {
        width: {
          min: 300,
          max: 1500
        },
        height: {
          min: 300,
          max: 1500
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.fixture);
  },
  methods: {
    resize(key, valid) {
      console.log("valid?", valid);
      this.fixture.dimensions[key] = event.target.value;
      // this.fixture.iconObject.resize()
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `v-model` to manage the input, you should explicitly call `validate` yourself, like this:

```
   <ValidationProvider
      :rules="`between:${fixture.limits[key].min},${fixture.limits[key].max}`"
      v-slot="{ errors, valid, validate }"
    >
      <v-text-field
        :value="fixture.dimensions[key]"
        @input="resize(key, $event, validate)"
        ...
      ></v-text-field>
    </ValidationProvider>

resize(key, value, validate) {
  validate(value).then(result => {
    console.log("valid???");
    console.log(result.valid);

    //either way update value
    this.fixture.dimensions[key] = value;
  });
}
```

In the callback from validate, you get a `result` object that includes whether the result is valid, and also which rules failed (in `result.failedRules`) and any error messages in an array (in `result.errors`).  See it working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-components-vuetify-ynll5